# How Do I Run "mvn install:install-file" in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In Netbeans, I can right click on a dependeny, and select "Manually install artifact", and it will run a maven install command like the one below:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=AppMeasurement_SE.jar -DgroupId=com.omniture -DartifactId=AppMeasurement_SE -Dversion=1.2.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Does Intellij have a similar feature, or should I learn to love the Linux command line prompt?

Comment: Nothing existing AFAIK. Does Netbeans provide a dialog to choose the GAV properties (groupId, artifactId, version) for that install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking IntelliJ IDEA to install the built artifact into maven local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754976/asking-intellij-idea-to-install-the-built-artifact-into-maven-local-repository)

Comment: @kingledion That doesn't really look like a duplicate though, or at least, the answer describes how to install the build of a project into the local repository, not how you install a random Jar dependency into the local repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plugin [intellij-maven](https://code.google.com/p/intellij-maven/wiki/IntelliJMaven) for this.

> "intellij-maven" is a maven project which can be used to create all of
>   IntelliJ IDEA (Community version) build artifacts with maven and to
>   install them into local maven repository.